# how to get menu item text using vc++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My problem is "how to know which menu item is 
clicked in visual studio 2005". i wrote some code using hook for monitoring 
WM_MENUSELECT..it is working fine for notepad,visual c++6.0 applications but 
when i use this code for VS-2005 it is not woking(these type of msgs are not 
generating when i click menuitem in VS2005)..

is there any other way to achive this...

please help me on this..i am really getting irritating becoz i am struggling 
from last one month...

any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: How do you start that "some code"? Is it Vc++ Plugin? Did you port that from Vc++ 6.0 to VC++ 2005?

Comment: That's because most likely the main window of Visual Studio 2005 doesn't have a menu bar at all. There is a component at the top which emulates it though.

Comment: i am generating this code using vc++6.0. it is not plugin.i write the code using hooks.

Hi avakar,
         is there no way to get menuitem text which user clicks? help me on this.i stuck with this.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you assume anything about how other people's software is implemented, you run the risk that they did something unusual or otherwise contrary to your expectations.  There is no perfect solution here.

Having said that, you could try hooking WM_COMMAND messages instead of WM_MENUSELECT.  That's more likely to be used by alternative toolbar/menu implementations.

Answer (score 0):

WM_MENUSELECT is a message from a Windows component. The same message is used, whether you're using C, C++, Delphi or any other language. A trivial difference like VC++6 and VC++8 won't matter. XP or Vista could matter, but I'd doubt it.

Now, it's possible that the actual cause of your difference is a different MFC version or something like that, but without code that would be speculating.